# gdb requires libpthread in QNX

Tags: gdb, qnx

So I am having a serious issue where the qnx version of `gdb` downloaded from foundry27 (the qnx software site) requires `libpthread.so.1` :

```
qnx:/root/# gdb 
ldd:FATAL: Could not load library libpthread.so.1
```

Now this is intriguing to me because according to [**here**](http://www.openqnx.com/newsgroups/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=19067) and my own past experience there is no pthread shared lib in QNX, the pthread content is part of libc.

I know this is a long shot but has anyone encountered this before?

EDIT:

```
qnx:/root/# uname -a
QNX qnx 6.5.0 2010/07/09-14:44:03EDT x86pc x86
```

I tried downloading qnx from here: 
http://community.qnx.com/sf/frs/do/viewRelease/projects.toolchain/frs.gdb.gdb_7_6_r863

I got the `nto-gdb` version because the options are as follows:

```
gdb-prereq-linux.tgz
gdb-prereq-win32.tgz
linux-gdb-7.6.tar.gz
win32-gdb-7.6.zip
nto-arm-gdb-7.6.tar.gz
nto-gdb-7.6.tar.gz
```

GDB info

```
ls -l $(which -a gdb)
lrwxrwxrwx  1 501   501 10 Jul 09 14:21 /usr/qnx650/host/qnx6/x86/usr/bin/gdb -> ntox86-gdb
```

GDB debug info

```
libs: load_object: attempt load of libpthread.so.1
debug: find_file:1151: name=libpthread.so.1 libpath=:/root/SMG/extern/libs/opendds/OpenDDS_ACE_TAO/ACE_wrappers/lib:/root/SMG/extern/libs/opendds/OpenDDS_ACE_TAO/DDS/lib:/usr/local/lib rpath=/usr/pkg/lib
debug: searchpath:1095: name=libpthread.so.1 path=/usr/pkg/lib amode=4 bufsize=1025
debug: searchpath:1119: trying /usr/pkg/lib/libpthread.so.1
debug: searchpath:1130:/usr/pkg/lib/libpthread.so.1: failed (No such file or directory)
debug: searchpath:1095: name=libpthread.so.1 path=:/root/SMG/extern/libs/opendds/OpenDDS_ACE_TAO/ACE_wrappers/lib:/root/SMG/extern/libs/opendds/OpenDDS_ACE_TAO/DDS/lib:/usr/local/lib amode=4 bufsize=1025
debug: searchpath:1119: trying libpthread.so.1
debug: searchpath:1130:libpthread.so.1: failed (No such file or directory)
debug: searchpath:1119: trying /root/SMG/extern/libs/opendds/OpenDDS_ACE_TAO/ACE_wrappers/lib/libpthread.so.1
debug: searchpath:1130:/root/SMG/extern/libs/opendds/OpenDDS_ACE_TAO/ACE_wrappers/lib/libpthread.so.1: failed (No such file or directory)
debug: searchpath:1119: trying /root/SMG/extern/libs/opendds/OpenDDS_ACE_TAO/DDS/lib/libpthread.so.1
debug: searchpath:1130:/root/SMG/extern/libs/opendds/OpenDDS_ACE_TAO/DDS/lib/libpthread.so.1: failed (No such file or directory)
debug: searchpath:1119: trying /usr/local/lib/libpthread.so.1
debug: searchpath:1130:/usr/local/lib/libpthread.so.1: failed (No such file or directory)
debug: searchpath:1095: name=libpthread.so.1 path=/proc/boot:/lib:/usr/lib:/lib/dll:/opt/lib amode=4 bufsize=1025
debug: searchpath:1119: trying /proc/boot/libpthread.so.1
debug: searchpath:1130:/proc/boot/libpthread.so.1: failed (No such file or directory)
debug: searchpath:1119: trying /lib/libpthread.so.1
debug: searchpath:1130:/lib/libpthread.so.1: failed (No such file or directory)
debug: searchpath:1119: trying /usr/lib/libpthread.so.1
debug: searchpath:1130:/usr/lib/libpthread.so.1: failed (No such file or directory)
debug: searchpath:1119: trying /lib/dll/libpthread.so.1
debug: searchpath:1130:/lib/dll/libpthread.so.1: failed (No such file or directory)
debug: searchpath:1119: trying /opt/lib/libpthread.so.1
debug: searchpath:1130:/opt/lib/libpthread.so.1: failed (No such file or directory)
debug: ldd:find_file:1175:libpthread.so.1: search failed
ldd:FATAL: Could not load library libpthread.so.1
```

Comment: Yes, pthread content is part of libc in QNX.  But you are not trying to run gdb on a QNX host, are you?  (your prompt says "qnx:" indeed)  If trying to run on QNX then the next question is if you are running a version of gdb built for QNX (and not, for example, for Linux)  Could you please update your question with the output of "uname -a" on the host that you are trying to run gdb on and also with the full link to the gdb archive that you pulled from F27 (don't want to guess which of possibly several versions posted there you may be using).

Comment: @maverick thanks for the response, the extra info has been added.

Comment: Thanks; the output of uname -a would be preferable as it provides the architecture too (I'll assume you are on x86).  Please add two more tests: 1. output of "ls -l $(which -a gdb)" (to see what exactly gdb is a symlink to as well as if there are more than one gdb-s on your target); 2. try running gdb with "DL_DEBUG=all gdb"; this will output a ton of library resolution info and may give a hint why it is trying to look for libpthread.so.1.  (The ntox86-gdb binary that I downloaded from the link does not include any reference to libpthread.so.1, so maybe it's pulled in via another lib.)

Comment: @maverick, added that info

Comment: Hi Ben, that did not reveal much.  Did you truncate the beginning of the log?  I was hoping that some hint would be before starting to look for libpthread.so.1.  If your log is actually longer than what you posted then could you please add a bit more context at the beginning? Also could you please run "use -i gdb" and paste the result?  This would ensure that we are looking at the same binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that the GDB executables provided on foundry 27 (the later ones) are built for QNX 6.6 which is cross compiled and deployed to a system rather than natively compiled. As in there is no native development and therefore the GDB executable wont work on QNX 6.5.

To solve this download a earlier version of the GDB executable.